# How to pull out non-matching values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the below code which does it's job very well, it detects whether all the value of `array1` appear in `array2`.

```
var array1 = ['Bob','Freddy', 'Johnson'];
var array2 = ['Bob', 'Johnson', 'Freddy'];
var isValid = 'no';

//Is the array inverted or contains an omission but no additions?
if (array1.every(v => array2.includes(v)) == true){ //All names appear on array2                
    isValid = 'yes';
} else { 
    isValid = 'no';
}

console.log('inverted = '+isValid); //yes
```

but given this array:

```
var array1 = ['Bob','Fredy', 'Johnson'];
```

I get the expect result of "no" however, I want to push further and ask the user whether we should consider 'fredy' equal to 'freddy'.

Here's what I've got for AFTER the user provides his answer:

```
var array1 = ['Bob','Fredy', 'Johnson'];
var array2 = ['Bob', 'Johnson', 'Freddy'];
var isValid = 'no';
var acceptable = 'yes'; // assume we asked the user the question and this is their answer

//Is the array inverted or contains an omission but no additions?
if (array1.every(v => array2.includes(v)) == true){ //All names appear on array2                
    isValid = 'yes';
} else { 
    isValid = 'no';

    console.log('Should we consider '+name1+' to be the same as '+name2+'?');

    if (acceptable == 'yes') {
        isValid = 'no';
    } 
}

console.log('inverted = '+isValid); //yes
```

My question is, how do I pick out `name1` and `name2` found in the below line?

```
console.log('Should we consider '+name1+' to be the same as '+name2+'?);
```

Consider also that many names (undetermined how many) in `array1` may differ in spelling from names in `array2`.

We should be ignoring all names in `array1` that match in `array2`.

Names in `array1` and `array2` may repeat. example:

```
var array1 = ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Freddy', 'Johnson'];
var array2 = ['Bob', 'Johnson', 'Bobb', 'Freddy']; // we should question if Bob matches Bobb

var array1 = ['Bobb', 'Bob', 'Freddy', 'Johnson'];
var array2 = ['Bob', 'Johnson', 'Bobb', 'Freddy']; // there is no questioning because all the names match, sequential order doesn't matter.

var array1 = ['Boy', 'Bobb', 'Freddy', 'Johnson'];
var array2 = ['Bob', 'Johnson', 'Freddy']; // we should question if Boy matches Bob, if not, then ask if Bobb matches Bobb

var array1 = ['Boy', 'Bobb', 'Freddy', 'Johnson'];
var array2 = ['Bob', 'Boi', 'Johnson', 'Freddy'];
```

in the last example, We should question if Boy matches Bob, if not, then ask if Bobb matches Bob, then ask if Boy matches Boi then ask if Boy matches Boi... all the while retaining where the user said yes. If the user says Boy matches Bob, then there is no need to ask if Bobb matches Bob. If at any point the user says there is no match at all for a given value, then isValid = no. (boy = bob: no + boy = boi: no, then isValid = no so don't even bother asking about Bobb).

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for an algorithm to find the edit distance between two strings. Here are some ideas:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-strings-are-at-edit-distance-one/ ||
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance ||
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665292/returns-true-if-the-two-strings-only-differ-by-one-character

Comment: No, it is far more ocmplex than that. The spellings can vary incredibly. Does Susan match Sue? etc